# Regular identity proof or disproof

Tags: regular-expressions

I have to prove or disprove the following identities:

1. $(RS+R)^*RS=(RR^*S)^*$
2. $(R+S)^*S=(R^*S)^*$
3. $S(RS+S)^*R=RR^*S(RR^*S)^*$

So what I tried:

1. Not same because LHS cannot generate $\epsilon$ while the RHS can.
2. Not same because LHS can generate $\epsilon$ while the RHS can.
3. Not same because LHS is the set of strings starting with $s\in S$ and ending with $r\in R$, so can generate $sr$ but the RHS cannot generate $sr$ .

Correct me please if I am wrong.

**EDIT:**
As Nathaniel suggested, for 2. ''Not same because LHS **cannot** generate $\epsilon$ while the RHS can.''

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: For the 2., a "can" should be a "cannot".

Comment: If I have to proof a regular identity $R=S$, what should I do? Using regular algebraic operations or just proving that a string $w\in R\iff w\in S$?

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.